# How to retrieve files to local machine when logged in to SSH?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

I know that you can grab files with `scp` like this:

```
scp user@remote_machine:/path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

However, I'd like to know if there is an easier way to do this, when I'm already logged on in ssh on the remote machine - that is, to avoid specifying username, hostname and absolute path to source?

Comment: Something like this? - http://superuser.com/questions/291034/is-it-possible-to-scp-from-a-remote-to-local-whilst-logged-into-the-remote-and-w

Comment: @Bibhas, yes, but it doesn't provide an *easier* way to solve the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/)?

> zssh (Zmodem SSH) is a program for interactively transferring files to a remote machine while using the secure  shell (ssh).  It  is intended to be a convenient alternative to scp , allowing to transfer files without  having  to  open another session and re-authenticate oneself.
>
> zssh  is an interactive wrapper for ssh

It uses the venerable rz, sz implementations of zmodem file transfer.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution so far. It is a bit inconvenient, but gets the job done. Do you happen to know how to transfer directories recursively? `find -type f | xargs sz` didn't help me for some weird reason, the only way I found was to compress them into some kind of archive, like this: `tar c directory/ | sz -`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the host information to your `~/.ssh/config`, something like:

```
Host            foo
HostName        foo.baz.com
User            bar
```

And then you can do `scp foo:~/path/to/file` instead of `scp bar@foo:~/path/to/file`, or alternatively you can setup an alias or function to do the same thing.

As for your actual question, I don't know. scp creates a new connection to transfer files and doesn't use the existing ssh connection.