# How can I copy a file from the machine I'm ssh'd into?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

I use my own laptop running Ubuntu to ssh to my school server (which is running another Linux distribution).

I do my assignments remotely like this, but I have an habit of putting all my files on Dropbox so that I can gain access of them anytime anywhere.

Question is:

for instance, I made a file named blah.cpp on the school server, thru ssh on my laptop, now I want to copy this file to my local machine into the Dropbox folder. What is the command to do that?

I've done the research and seems like `scp` and `sftp` are the solution but I find it hard to understand what exactly I should do with them.

Comment: `scp` to copy file from remote host `sshfs` to mount a remote folder onto a local one

Comment: but like in this case, how do i copy the blah.cpp to my dropbox folder(/home/u/Dropbox)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to SCP from a remote to local whilst logged into the remote?](http://superuser.com/q/291034/354511) or [How to retrieve files to local machine when logged in to SSH?](http://superuser.com/q/380127/354511)

Comment: Would it be possible to copy directly to your Dropbox account from the school server?

Answer (score 2):

Run this command on your laptop, not ssh'ing or anything, just open up a terminal and run it.
(replace some of the values perhaps to make it work)

```
scp youraccountnameonremotemachine@remotemachine:fileinyourhomedirectory .
```

This copies the file 'fileinyourhomedirectory' in your home directory (cpn. obvious) on the remote machine to the current path (='.') of your laptop.

For your example:

```
scp  anson@remoteserver:blah.cpp /home/u/Dropbox/
```

This is all easily understood, if you just read the contents of the manual of scp:

```
man scp
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and I ve got another 2 question.                  1:can I scp folders?                                                           2: now I have already sshed into the server, can I copy the file blah.cpp to my local laptop from within the server?                        And thanks but the manual page seemed very unhelpful and not straight forward to me.

Comment: 1: use the -r parameter, it's the acronym for _recursive_

2: if you ssh to a machine, you're executing commands _on that machine_ I don't think there is some kind of backlink to the machine you ssh'd from. So your copy-action would be a copy-to-remote action, the remote being your laptop. It's probably easier to just fire up Filezilla: http://filezilla-project.org/